# vba outlook unified inbox w/ ONLY Select Mailboxes (windows desktop version)

Tags: vba, outlook

Unified for all mailboxes works with below code. **I can't find right syntax or example to allow me to see some other mailboxes together**.

Example: you have four mailboxes setup in outlook, A, B, C, D. The below code unifies/shows all inboxes with the VBA Search.
The Question: **I would like to modify code to show/unifiy ONLY mailboxes B, C, & D.** to combine a subset of mailboxes, not all.

I suspect I could set the value of currentfolder somehow...but this would only be one folder at a time?  Thanks!!!!!

I have searched for awhile for this, thanks for your time!!!

```
`    Sub UnifiedInboxThisWeek()
    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    txtSearch = "folder:Inbox received: (this week)"
    myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders
    Set myOlApp = Nothing
    End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. You can search in a single store, but not multiple profiles simultaneously. However, you can get access to shared mailboxes by using the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. So, you can run multiple searches against different stores.

Consider using the AdvancedSearch method of the Application class which has the following key benefits:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Using the `Scope` parameter, you can specify one or more folders in the same store, but you may not specify multiple folders in multiple stores. To specify multiple folders in the same store for the `Scope` parameter, use a comma character between each folder path and enclose each folder path in single quotes. For default folders such as `Inbox` or `Sent Items`, you can use the simple folder name instead of the full folder path. For example, the following two lines of code represent valid `Scope` parameters:

```
Scope = "'Inbox', 'Sent Items'"
```

and you can also use the folder path:

```
Scope = "'" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).FolderPath _  
    & "','" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).FolderPath & "'"
```

Read more about the AdvancedSearch method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance on this. I have not had a chance to go through it all yet but it looks very helpful! I will hopefully go through it later this week.